# Prove indirectly: $\forall$ $,  \in \mathbb{Z}$, if $^3 + ^3$ is even, then $ + $ is even.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

I'm stuck after negating the statement to there exists $x,y \in\mathbb{Z}$, $^3 + ^3$ is even and $ + $ is odd.

Comment: A way to start is to use the assumption that x+y is odd. That means you can start by  assuming x is even and y is odd, then continue to get a contradiction. Then for the other possibility you assume x is odd and y is even, and again continue to a contradiction.

Comment: Hint: $(x^3+y^3) - (x+y) = (x^3 - x) + (y^3 - y) = (x-1)\,x\,(x+1) - (y-1)\,y\,(y+1) = \small{\text{even} - \text{even}}$

Comment: Alternative : $(x^3 + y^3) = (x+y)(x^2 - xy + y^2).$  If $(x+y)$ is odd, then $x,y$ have different parity.  In that event, $(x^2 - xy + y^2)$ will also be odd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proof by contrapositive: suppose $x+y$ odd. Then WLOG assume $x$ even and $y$ odd.

Since $x$ even, $x^3$ even, and $y$ odd, so $y^3$ odd. Thus $x^3 + y^3$ even + odd = odd, so $x^3 + y^3$ odd. QED

Comment: This is not really a proof by contradiction, but rather a [proof by contrapositive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_contrapositive).

Comment: @Gary thanks, edited

Comment: You have to change a bit more than that if you understand what proof by contrapositive means.

Comment: @Gary why? We assumed the negation of the consequent, and derived the negation of the precedent. The rest is implied

Comment: You are still mentioning contradiction at the end.

Comment: @Gary the claim to be proven is $P -> Q$, $P$ is $x^3+y^3$ even. $Q$ is $x+y$ even. Therefore, we assume not $Q$ and try and show not $P$ - that is, try and show that $x^3 + y^3$ not even. The contradiction at the end shows this. QED

Comment: Yes but then no need to assume it is even and saying contradiction because it is not. Just conclude it is odd because it is a difference of an odd and an even.

Comment: @Gary you're right, edited again

Answer (score 1):

The contrapositive of the statement: $\forall x,y \in \mathbb{Z}: (x^3+y^3) \text{ is even} \text{ then } (x+y) \text{ is even}$ is:
$$\forall x,y \in \mathbb{Z}: (x+y) \text{ is odd} \text{ then }(x^3 + y^3) \text{ is odd}$$

Now assume that $x+y$ is odd. This means $x$ and $y$ have different parity, i.e., $x$ is odd and $y$ is even, or $x$ is even and $y$ is odd. Either way, we have $xy$ is even and is $x^2 + y^2$ odd (because either $x^2$ is odd or $y^2$ is odd). From these results, we have $x^2-xy+y^2 = (x^2+y^2)-xy$ is odd.

Observe that $x^3 + y^3 = (x+y)(x^2-xy+y^2)$, since both $x+y$ and $x^2-xy+y^2$ is odd, their product, namely $x^3+y^3$, is also odd.